# Mongoimport import error - tab delimited CSV detected as JSON

Tags: mongodb, csv

I'm trying to import a `.csv` file into a MongoDB database with the `mongoimport` utility. The `.csv` file has a headerline as follows:

`countryCode    streetName  postalCode  placeName   adminName1  adminCode1  adminName2  adminCode2  adminName3  adminCode3  latitude    longitude   accuracy`

And the rest of the data is structured as following:

`GB Broad Street    AB10 1AA    George St/Harbour Ward  Scotland    SCT         Aberdeen City   S12000033   57.1482280891232    -2.09664786079318   6`

I get the following error when using the command:

`mongoimport -d mydb -c locations --file geodata.csv --headerline
error validating settings: can not use --headerline when input type is JSON`

Can anyone tell me why? The `csv` file only has 130,000 records so it's not a size issue.

Comment: Where are you saying that this is a CSV file? I think you should include "--type csv" in your import command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **--headerline** can be used only for csv and tsv file formats.

When you are importing CSV, please use "--type csv" in your command.

> --headerline If using --type csv or --type tsv, uses the first line as field names. Otherwise, mongoimport will import the first line as a
>   distinct document.
>
> If you attempt to include --headerline when importing JSON data,
>   mongoimport will return an error. --headerline is only for csv or tsv
>   imports.

Comment: That is weird; MongoDB does not detect the type of file based on file extension? Any idea why this is the case?